# Java - HBase Client stuck on Session establishment complete

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to a remote HBase cluster to retrieve data, but the client continuously hangs up at the same place:

```
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=rap-es-1.hidden.host.com
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_75
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75.x86_64/jre
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=CassandraBulkTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/data/cassandra-import
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=rap-cdh-1.hidden.host.com:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 7831@rap-es-1.hidden.host.com
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server rap-cdh-1.hidden.host.com/141.161.88.163:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to rap-cdh-1.hidden.host.com/141.161.88.163:2181, initiating session
15/02/11 11:32:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server rap-cdh-1.hidden.host.com/141.161.88.163:2181, sessionid = 0x14764e5eb66024b, negotiated timeout = 60000
```

I've read around and it sounds like it SHOULD be a discrepancy between client/server versions, but I've checked my versions:

```
-sh-4.1$ hbase version
15/02/11 11:38:16 INFO util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0
15/02/11 11:38:16 INFO util.VersionInfo: Subversion file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0 -r Unknown
15/02/11 11:38:16 INFO util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jenkins on Mon May 27 20:22:05 PDT 2013

-sh-4.1$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0
Subversion file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 48a9315b342ca16de92fcc5be95ae3650629155a
Compiled by jenkins on Mon May 27 19:45:25 PDT 2013
From source with checksum a4218d77f9b12df4e3e49ef96f9d357d
This command was run using /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar
```

And my pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.94.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've also tried:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What is weird is that the program runs fine when I'm running it within Netbeans IDE, but as soon as I try to run it from another server, it hangs right there. Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, you have to use the cloudera jar. You can either change the repo of your pom.xml to cloudera: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html
or you can take the Jar for /opt/cloudera